# clusterstate corruption after adding new ZK hosts to solr cloud

Tags: solr

I have a solr cloud 5.5.4 implementation with Zookeeper 3.4.10. In order to migrate data to new solr nodes I have added 3 new ZK hosts and added them to the ensemble. I then modified every solr.in.sh file so include all the ZK hosts. The goal is to remove the old solr hosts and ZK hosts and replace them with the new ones. This is a datacenter migration.

This process was successfully tested. In production however many collections' shards have lost their Range. It was this (example):
"range":"80000000-7fffffff"
Now its null.
Other changes in the state:
replicationFactor has changed to 1 (was 2)
router has changed to implicit (was compositeId)
Also, the clusterstate.json on the admin UI (cloud/tree) that used to be empty, now has the entire cloud's state values. Each individual collection no longer has a state.json file. It's all been merged into the one clusterstate.json.

What I think I need to do is fix the state for each collection that has a null range (and the wrong router). Every collection was made the exact same way (years ago) with a compositeId and ranged shards with a rep factor of 2. I had thought I would be dealing with individual state.json files, one for each collection. That is what I was prepared for. I am shocked to see all the state now wrapped into the clusterstate.json.

I am wary (scared to) update the clusterstate file since it represents the entire cloud. Seems risky. But I assume I can't add a state.json file to ZK if that collections' state is in the master clusterstate. Has anyone run across issues like this and how did you fix them?

Comment: I realized now that production has been running since I had solr 4. So that must be why there are no collection state.json files. Even though most of the collections have been created since solr 5 was live, ZK must be continuing to use the older clusterstate.json file.